# Changing Item with animation WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, animation

I have created an itemscontrol and bound a observablecollection named as `Items`. I have Image in my datatemplate. I need to change my item in every 2 minutes with `FadeIn` and `FadeOut` animations cyclically. How I can achieve that ? Here is my code

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,10" 
                   Source="{Binding}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Have a look at [Transitionals](https://transitionals.codeplex.com/)

Comment: You could attach a BeginStoryboardAction to a Loaded Event Trigger on the Item Template to fire off a Storyboard opacity animation and the same with Unloaded.